# Error while connecting to oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, connection

I have an error while trying to connect to oracle db.
The error is:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

When i launch the application and login, sometimes this error occur and sometimes not. in other words when logging into the system, the error pops only for certain users!

what might be the issue?

Comment: There are lots of reasons this error can happen, most of which have to do with the client-side configuration.  Your question is about the same as "My car won't start, what could be wrong?" and cannot be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with the TNSNAMES.ORA file in the Oracle Client installation for those affected users. Check the TNS definitions.

Comment: but the users are stored in the database.. all in the same table

Comment: @lin - TNS errors are at a network level. Database contents are irrelevant in this case. By "users" I mean the computers that use your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is 98% of the time an issue on the user's client (typically PC) with missing/wrong tnsnames.ora and/or sqlnet.ora files.  Since it works for some users, make sure the files sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora exist for the problem users, and that they are the same version.  You can also check the value of registry variable TNS_ADMIN, and look for the presence of multiple oracle homes.  Sometimes developers inadvertently modify this situation by installing extra goodies, and then they don't pick up new changes.